# DOMException: Invalid image request

Tags: javascript

Im investigating a some code that seems to be working in chrome and not in firefox nor ie.
The code is for lazy loading images. And this is the part that fails

```
image.decode().then(() => {
                        this._handleLoad(image);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                        this._handleError(image);
                    });
```

And this is the image:

```
<img class="ix-lazyimg--loading" data-src="https://placeimg.com/480/270/peopl" data-srcset="https://placeimg.com/960…mg.com/320/180/arch 320w" data-sizes="(min-width: 520px) 500px, 50vw" alt="A kitten!" loading="lazy" sizes="(min-width: 520px) 500px, 50vw" srcset="https://placeimg.com/960…mg.com/320/180/arch 320w" src="https://placeimg.com/480/270/peopl">
```

Think its really wierd that it works on chrome and no where else.

Br

Comment: IE does not support arrow functions...

Comment: I assume `https://placeimg.com/960…mg.com/320/180/arch 320w` is a typo....

Comment: IE does not support the ```.decode()``` function either

Answer (score 0):

I get this error whenever I call `decode()` on any `<img loading="lazy">`. And I cannot say for certain without testing, but I suspect that any image with a `srcset` might not behave as intended before it is appended to or imported by a document.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is on the right track. For those still encountering this issue, I've managed to get around it by, removing the srcset attribute from the image element, **before calling the decode function** and then adding the srcset back to the element again.

Turns out trying to call the decode function on an image element with the srcset attribute on Firefox (v118.0.2), will result in the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: invalid image request.`